# Multiple function definition inside a whenevent

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, event-detection

I am trying to implement a whenevent inside a NdSolve such that when a particle reaches within earths radius its position becomes a constant <0,0,0>. When I set one function x[t]-> 0 it works. However multiple functions do not work.

```
sol[x0_, y0_, z0_, v0x_, v0y_, v0z_] := 
  Flatten[NDSolve[{x''[t] == -G*
       M ((x[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(3/2)), 
     y''[t] == -(G*M (y[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(3/2)), 
     z''[t] == -G*M ((z[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(3/2)), 
     x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0, x'[0] == v0x,
     y'[0] == v0y, z'[0] == v0z, 
     WhenEvent[(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(1/2) == 
       6871000, {x[t] -> 0, y[t] -> 0, z[t] -> 0}]}, {x[t], y[t], 
     z[t]}, {t, 0, 10000}]];
```

Comment: Please post the full code. What is the `G` and `M`?

Comment: G is the gravitational constant and M is the mass of the earth. They are constants defined earlier

Comment: it also helps to show the call you made, and also explain why/how **However multiple functions do not work** mean. i.e. how will one running your code know that it did not work?

Comment: **They are constants defined earlier** The comment meant that you should include these in your question. Do not let others do the work that you are supposed to do. Your code should be self contained and complete.

Comment: sat3 = Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. 
  sol[136398.27159769333, -7.36816539739529*10^6, 
   0, -4.2, -4.2, -0.1]]. Is the call I am evaluating. When in the the NDSolve I solely set x[t]->0 and plot it on a parametricplot3d the x value stays at 0.

Comment: It's harder to help if you don't include an [MWE](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/what-do-we-mean-by-a-self-contained-minimal-working-example). -- BTW, the ODE is undefined at $(0,0,0)$, so the event action would cause `NDSolve` to throw an error. Maybe you want `"StopIntegration"` instead? (Also `QuantityMagnitude@
 UnitConvert[Entity["Planet", "Earth"][EntityProperty["Planet", "Radius"]],  "Meters"]` has a 3 where you have an 8, but since the Earth is not a sphere, I don't know if that matters to you.)